# Creating Excel worksheets using Parallel.For and EPPlus

Tags: c#, epplus

I am using the [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) library to create an Excel workbook with many worksheets.  I was wondering if it is safe to build the worksheets in parallel.  I could not find a mention in the (limited) documentation if the library supports this kind of behavior:

```
package = new ExcelPackage();
int start = 1;
int end = 100;

Parallel.For(start, end; s =>
{
    var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Worksheet" + s.ToString());
    //routine to populate data here
});
```

Comment: Just glancing at their source code, it appears to be built with at least some thought to multi-threading. That, at least, is promising. As a side note, be wary, as your `Parallel.For` has absolutely no guarantee of putting the worksheets in any particular order, if that matters to you.

Comment: Order of the worksheets does not matter to me; I just want to optimize workbook creation.  I have all of the data ready ahead of time and just need to slice/dice/filter for each worksheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a short look for the source code: https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/blob/master/EPPlus/ExcelWorksheets.cs

As you can see, the Add method calls the AddSheet method that uses lock(...) to make the operation thread-safe, so yes, you can use the Parallel.For.

Comment: I was hoping for a definitive "I've done it and it works fine" answer and possibly so areas where I should exercise caution.  I guess I will just have to look at the source and deal with any bumps as I go along.

Comment: @codechurn about 1 year later, what were your findings?

Comment: @w33z33 I have been doing it for that entire year without one problem. In the Visual Studio debugger I will occasionally (once out of every 300) times get a goofy error.  I have never had a problem in the production deployed code.