# epplus by use "parallel.for" cause unexcepted exception

Tags: c#, excel, multithreading

I used epplus 4.1.0.0 for create excel files. Following are part of my code.
If I use for loop to run it. It's OK. While I use Parallel.For to run, it cause unexcepted exception like null reference exception or it said can't setup color if pattern type not set. But sometimes the code won't raise any exception. And the output excel file is OK.

```
Parallel.For(0, dt.Rows.Count, i =>
{
   worksheet.Cells[StartRow + i, 1].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
   worksheet.Cells[StartRow + i, 1].Formula = "O" + (StartRow + i).ToString() + "&\"^\" &V" + (StartRow + i).ToString();
   worksheet.Cells[StartRow + i, 1].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Orange);
   worksheet.Cells[StartRow + i, 2].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
   worksheet.Cells[StartRow + i, 2].Formula = "IF(ISERR(W" + (StartRow + i).ToString() + "*(60/AH" + (StartRow + i).ToString() + ")),\"\",W" + (StartRow + i).ToString() + "*(60/AH" + (StartRow + i).ToString() + "))";
   worksheet.Cells[StartRow + i, 2].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Orange);
   worksheet.Cells[StartRow + i, 3].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
   worksheet.Cells[StartRow + i, 3].Formula = "G" + (StartRow + i).ToString() + "&\"^\" &V" + (StartRow + i).ToString();
   worksheet.Cells[StartRow + i, 3].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Orange);
   worksheet.Cells[StartRow + i, 4].Value = dt.Rows[i][8].ToString().Substring(0, dt.Rows[i][8].ToString().Length - 3);
   worksheet.Cells[StartRow + i, 5].Value = dt.Rows[i][9].ToString().Substring(0, dt.Rows[i][9].ToString().Length - 3);
   worksheet.Cells[StartRow + i, 6].Value = dt.Rows[i][8].ToString();
   worksheet.Cells[StartRow + i, 7].Value = dt.Rows[i][9].ToString();
   worksheet.Cells[StartRow + i, 8].Value = dt.Rows[i][4].ToString().Trim();
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems EPPlus Worksheet API is not a thread safe (at least some cell operations). Different worksheets could be processed in parallel, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34911085/creating-excel-worksheets-using-parallel-for-and-epplus).

You can check [EPPlus source code](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) - it contains some locks, and possibly it should be thread safe (only its author knows that); you can add an issue on github if you feel that you really need to process one worksheet in parallel.

In most case this has a little sense, as internally EPPlus uses locks for accessing shared collections that store worksheet data. If your code that works with EPPlus API works slowly, try to do the following:

- do not mix time-consuming operations (data preparation, calculations) with code that uses EPPlus API
- reuse ExcelRange objects

smth like

```
var cellStyle = worksheet.Cells[StartRow + i, 1].Style;
cellStyle.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Orange);
cellStyle.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think the thread safe is the most important reason why my code can't run.